# DATE ADD function error in workbench

Tags: mysql

My insert is failing due to error 1292, incorrect datetime value:'0'

I've read up on that error and I can't see what I'm doing that would trigger it.

My two date columns on the table to which I'm inserting are both set to DATE format. The source date column for those values is p.date and it is type int(20). Maybe those conflict with the DATE_ADD function.

I'm trying to convert them to YYYY-MM-DD format with intervals.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

```
INSERT INTO newTable (
  sku_id, 
  group_id, 
  customer, 
  start_date, 
  expire_date, 
  quantity, 
  order_num
)
SELECT 
  s.id,
  s.grpID,
  p.cst,
  DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT( p.date , CHAR (20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS start_date,
  DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT( p.date , CHAR (20)), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    INTERVAL 127 DAY) AS expire_date,
  p.quantity,
  p.invoice
FROM
  skus s
    INNER JOIN
    temp p ON s.body = p.body 
      AND s.cov = p.cov
      AND s.col = p.col
WHERE
  p.quantity = 1
ORDER BY p.invoice DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

so p.date has 20160202 and I need 2016-02-02

Comment: @hnorman p.date is an INT, are you storing seconds since the UNIX epoch in p.date?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data so we can try and recreate the issue? Thanks

Comment: Sorry no it's an int so it stores 20160202 no hours/minutes/seconds

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT(20160202, CHAR(20)),'%Y-%m-%d'); returns 2016-02-02 for me. Do you have any 'dates' where the value is in the format ddmmYYYY e.g. 02022016?

Answer (score 0):

If `p.date` is in seconds since the epoch, and you want to return `YYYY-MM-DD`, then i'd change your `DATE_ADD` functions to the following:

```
DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME(p.date) + INTERVAL 7 DAY ) as start_date,
DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME(p.date) + INTERVAL 7 DAY ) as start_date,
```